# Query Fine Tune

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have simple query which is taking around 7-8 seconds for to retreive the data from database which I want to fine tune further to 2-3 seconds.

Table :

```
UpdateDateTime | field1 | field2 |..... FieldN.
```

Query is :

```
Select *  
from Table with (nolock)  
where UpdateDateTime Between D1 and D2  
Order By UpdateDateTIme
```

I have created Clustered Index On `UpdateDateTime`

What could be done further to increase its Efficiency?

Comment: It depends on so many, many things.  Is your server well-equipped?  Are you running the query over the internet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reduce the number of columns returned is the obvious answer, then create a covering (nonclustered) index on `UpdateDateTIme`  and `INCLUDE` the other selected columns.

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX NC_MyCoveringIndex 
   ON Table(UpdateDateTime)
      INCLUDE (Col1, Col2, ..., ColN)
```

[Ref](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188783%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).

[**Note**: It's not ideal to create a wide covering index that includes all the columns in the table.]

A lot depends on how selective your `WHERE` clause is. If it returns (approximately) greater than 10% of the number of rows in the table, then the optimiser will probably just scan the clustered index anyway.

That's pretty much it. Beyond you need to take a look at your hardware, and how much data you are pulling across the wire.

Comment: But I need all the fields. Could you please tell me how to create covering Index, is it :  
Create Index <> On <> Include ()

Comment: you shouldn't create a covering index over all the columns really. Not ideal. But Yes that is the syntax.